# CSV в ассоциативный массив

Tags: php, массивы, csv

Есть csv такого формата

```
'01.09.2021';'День Знаний'
'30.10.2021';'Хэллоуин'
```

Как распарсить его в ассоциативный массив такого вида

```
$events = array(
    '01.09.2021'    => 'День Знаний',
    '30.10.2021'    => 'Хэллоуин',
);
```

Comment: В цикле. Все операции по созданию массивов производятся в цикле.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php там есть и пример разбора файла, у тебя два поля, первое кидай в ключи массива, второе в значение массива

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$File="c:\\text\\text.csv";    
$file10 = file($File, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
    
    foreach ($file10 as $key => $value) {
        $sen=explode(';', $value);
        $stroka[$sen[0]]=$sen[1];
    }
    print_r($stroka);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от объёма файла. Предположим, что он небольшой. Тогда:

1. Считать файл

   ```
   $fileData = file_get_contents('1.csv');
   ```
2. Сделать разбор CSV-строки в массив с помощью **[str_getcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-getcsv.php)**, где вторым параметром указать разделитель строк

   ```
   $dataArray = str_getcsv($fileData, "\n");
   ```
3. Создать переменную, куда будет складываться результат (предположим `$result = []`);
4. Пробежаться циклом по `$dataArray` применяя к каждому элементу функцию разбиения по разделителю **[explode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)** и складывать в результирующий

Comment: str_getcsv делает не то что вы думаете

Comment: @Ипатьев там в комментариях к функции на php.net есть такой костыль))

Comment: @Jean-Claude не подумал. но тогда это втройне костыль, использовать связку  file_get_contents / вывернутая наизнанку  str_getcsv вместо file()